# How to save newlines in file as LF (Unix convention)?

Tags: java, unix, newline

I want to save my files as UTF-8 but newlines must not be done with CRLF (Windows convention), but as LF (Unix convetion). How to I do that?

Is it just enough to write "\n" at the end of the line, like this:

```
String data = "";
data += "My text line 1\n";
data += "My text line 2\n";
```

?

My file is saved properly so that every line is in it's row and that is good. How do I know is that Windows or Linux convention?

If this information is needed for my question, I'm saving my file with this:

```
new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename), "UTF-8"));
```

But how do I know if my newlines are saved as LF and not as CRLF ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this works. The file will contain just LF as line separator. To verify, open the file with your favorite hex editor.

Answer (score -1):

Java will write the line ending characters you have specified. So `write("test\n")` is Unix LF and `write("test\r\n")` is Windows CRLF.

There are some functions which however automatically use the line ending of the current OS. This includes `printf("test%n")` as well as `println()` or `BufferedWriter.newLine()`. The currently used default line ending is available with [System.lineSeparator()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--) or the `"line.separator"` system property..

Comment: Windows CRLF is `\r\n`. What you've used, `\n\r`, isn't a line terminator in any computer system known to man.